# Understanding Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to work out how to run NamedRunnable from my public static void main.
I am essentially experimenting with 2 ways to run my thread the first is to create and define a thread the next is to define a class and then implement runnable.

Here is my code

```
package threads;

public class Threads extends Thread{
private final String name; // The name of this thread



public static void main(String[] args) {

long lStartTime = System.nanoTime();
Threads greetings = new Threads("Fred");
Threads greetings1 = new Threads("Betty");
NamedRunnable greetings2 = new NamedRunnable("Ralph");//it is here i cant   seem to create an instance of Named Runnable and therefore call start



greetings.start();
greetings1.start();
greetings2.start();



long lEndTime = System.nanoTime();

long difference = lEndTime - lStartTime;

System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + difference);
}
public Threads(String name) { 
    this.name = name; 
} 



public void run() { // The run method prints a message to standard output. 

System.out.println("Greetings from thread ’" + name + "’!"); 

}


public class NamedRunnable implements Runnable { 
    private final String name;
// The name of this Runnable. 
public NamedRunnable(String name) { // Constructor gives name to object. 
    this.name = name; } 
public void run() { // The run method prints a message to standard output. 
    System.out.println("Greetings from runnable ’" + name +"’!"); } }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread and Runnable are 2 different things:

A Thread is an object that maps to an OS thread. Calling start on a Thread allocates and executes a thread.

A Runnable describes a task to be performed.

A Thread is only one way to perform a Runnable. You can run a Runnable either using a Thread, as in

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
};
new Thread(myRunnable).start();
```

or you can submit a Runnable to an ExecutorService and let the service decide how to execute it:

```
executorService.submit(myRunnable);
```

or you can execute the Runnable in the current thread:

```
myRunnable.run();
```

As a convenience someone decided to make Thread implement Runnable, possibly so they could write demos with slightly less code.

Comment: @ Nathan Hughes ..this is the paragraph i am trying to get my head round The Thread class has a constructor that takes a Runnable as its parameter. When an object that implements the Runnable interface is passed to that constructor, the run() method of the thread will simply call the run() method from the Runnable, and calling the thread’s start() method will create a new thread of control in which the Runnable’s run() method is executed.

Comment: @Mr Assistance: "calling the thread’s start() method will create a new thread of control in which the Runnable’s run() method is executed": this is correct, what don't you get?

Comment: so basically the runnable interface deﬁnes a single method, public void run() as highlighted in your first bit of code..

Comment: @MrAssistance: yes, that is all there is to it.

Comment: Many thanks for helping with that - it now makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Pass a `Runnable` to a `Thread` to run it, or use another class like `ExecutorService`.

```
new Thread( greetings2 ).start();
```

BTW, this is probably a terrible idea:

```
public class Threads extends Thread{
   //...

    public void run() { // The run method prints a message to standard output. 

        System.out.println("Greetings from thread ’" + name + "’!"); 

    }
```

All sorts of confusion can result from overriding methods like `run()` and `start()`.  You change their semantics (i.e., what they do) completely when you do this.  Use `Thread` without sub-classing it or use classes like `ExecutorService`.  Sub-classing `Thread` is like so last century.

Comment: Hello i cant seem to get this to work, however i dont want to extend thread i wish to implement runnable

Answer (score 1):

One of the [Thread class constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable)) accepts Runnable instance as mentioned here:

> ```
> public Thread(Runnable target)
> ```
>
> Allocates a new Thread object. This constructor has the same effect as Thread (null, target, gname), where gname is a newly
>   generated name. Automatically generated names are of the form
>   "Thread-"+n, where n is an integer.
>
> Parameters:
>   target - the object whose run method is invoked when this thread is started. If null, this classes run method does nothing.

So do like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(greetings2);
t.start();
```

When the thread is started it will kick of your `NamedRunnable.run` method.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the ExexutorService to relize the function, last week , i read some book , since java 1.5 ,it is the best answer.

```
  public class LiftOff implements Runnable {
      protected int countDown = 10;
      private static int taskCount = 0;
      private final id = taskCount++; 
      public LiftOff(){}
      public LiftOff(int counDown) {
            this.countDown = countDown;
      }

      public String status() {
      return "#" + id + "(" + (countDown >0 ? countDown : "LiftOff!") + ")";
       }

      public void run() {
       while(countDown-- > 0) {
         System.out.pritln(status);
          Thread.yield();
         }
      }
   }



    public class Test {   
          public static void main(Strig args[]) {
                ExectorService execu = Exector.newCachedThreadPool();
                for(int i = 0; i++) {
                   execu.execute(new LiftOff());
                    execu.shutdown();
                 }

         }
  }
```